# Inserting html div elements into 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
var mainCube = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mainCubeClass'));//assume there are **three**
if (mainCube !== null) {
    for (k = 0; k < mainCube.length; k++) {
        mainCube[k] = new Array(15);
    } //fill each slot in the array with an array of 15 slots
    document.write("Check1");//everything good so far
    for (var i = 0; i < mainCube.length; i++) {
        document.write("Check2");//okay, still good
        for (var j = 0; j < mainCube[i].length; j++) { //this is now 15
            document.write("Check3");//everything still as expected
            mainCube[i][j] = document.createElement('div');
            mainCube[i][j].className = '.letterPix';
            mainCube[i].appendChild(mainCube[i][j]);
            document.write("Check4"); //doesn't execute
        }
    }
```

I need to enter `div` elements into a 2dimensional array. I want to create these divs dynamically because the `.mainCubeClass` may vary from page to page. I've done this with 1d arrays but I've hit a wall now that I cannot seem to get past with 2d arrays and I've narrowed the area of error to the spot in between "check3" and "check4" but I can't seem to find a solution. Does anyone think they may know how to insert every new element created into a slot of my 2d array.

For example, if there are 3 `.mainCubeClasse` then there should be a total of 45 elements being created and inserted at position `mainCube[0][0]`...`mainCube[0][1]` etc. etc.

Comment: `mainCube[i].appendChild`missing `[j]` I guess. You should look at the console to find errors

Comment: How are you running this code? Note that if it's not during initial page load, that first `document.write` will wipe out all content on the page. Look at using the fully-featured debugger built into your browser for debuggin, not `document.write` statements.

Comment: **^^Agreed with the above comment^^** I recommend using `console.log();`

Comment: Okay, will see about using `console.log()` then thanks for the advice. However, it is running during page load.

Comment: @NewToJS: No, not `console.log`; **the debugger**. `console.log`-style debugging was outdated before JavaScript was even created (we used to call it `printf`-style debugging) in all but a few use cases.

Comment: Something I just saw right now was that, basically `mainCube` is an array with three [element] in them. Then, a bit before _check1_ when I run the for loop to make it a 2d array am I possibly **replacing** those elements with empty arrays?

Comment: T.J. what do you recommend I use to debug?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm agreeing with your post but recommending console.log() as a personal recommendation as i find it great for making sure my functions are running and the correct content/values are being passed. Sorry, Mixed post.

Comment: @Bryan: The *"...fully-featured debugger built into your browser..."* You probably access it via F12 and/or Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Shift+I on Macs). If not, it'll be on the menus as "developer tools" or similar.

Comment: I don't know who's answer to pick they're both really good what do I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. There's no point in the `if (mainCube != null)` check, you'll never have `null` there. You may have an empty array, but not `null`.
2. In your first loop, the `mainCube[k] = new Array(15)` line *replaces* the element that you had in that position with a blank array. So looking up the elements in the first place was pointless.
3. `mainCube[i][j].className = '.letterPix';` Class names really, really shouldn't start with a `.` (I don't know whether it's technically allowed, but it's a very bad idea.)
4. Re `mainCube[i].appendChild(mainCube[i][j]);`: Arrays don't have an `appendChild` method, but `mainCube[i]` is an array.

I have no idea what you want to do with the elements you originally looked up, but if you want to create a 3x15 array of `div` elements, then:

```
var i, j, mainCube, a, div;
mainCube = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    mainCube[i] = a = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 15; ++j) {
        // Create the div
        mainCube[i][j] = div = document.createElement('div');

        // Add class and such to div
        div.className = "letterPix"; // No dot!

        // Append it to something
    }
}
```

If your goal is to create those 15 divs and append them to the elements you're looking up initially, then:

```
var i, j, mainCube, a, div, elements;
elements = document.querySelectorAll(".mainCubeClass");
mainCube = [];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    mainCube[i] = a = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 15; ++j) {
        // Create this div
        mainCube[i][j] = div = document.createElement('div');

        // Add class and such to div
        div.className = "letterPix"; // No dot!

        // Append it to the mainCubeClass element
        elements[i].appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var i, j, mainCube, a, div, elements;
  elements = document.querySelectorAll(".mainCubeClass");
  mainCube = [];
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      mainCube[i] = a = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 15; ++j) {
          // Create this div
          mainCube[i][j] = div = document.createElement('div');

          // Add class and such to div
          div.className = "letterPix";

          // Append it to the mainCubeClass element
          elements[i].appendChild(div);
      }
  }
})();
```

```css
.mainCubeClass {
  border: 1px solid #02c;
}
.letterPix {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCubeClass"></div>
<div class="mainCubeClass"></div>
<div class="mainCubeClass"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have deleted the `!==null` check, its useful for the rest of my code but I should have explained it. Or it **was** useful, I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the mistake of was making of mixing up elements with array elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are chaning the array `mainCube` to an array of arrays, so `mainCube[i].appendChild(mainCube[i][j])` will fail because `mainCube[i]` is an array not a element

```
var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mainCubeClass')); //assume there are **three**
if (els !== null) {
    //use a separate array to store the cube
    var mainCube = new Array()
    for (k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {
        mainCube.push(new Array(15))
    } //fill each slot in the array with an array of 15 slots
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mainCube[i].length; j++) { //this is now 15
            mainCube[i][j] = document.createElement('div');
            mainCube[i][j].className = '.letterPix';
            mainCube[i][j].innerHTML = i + ':' + j
            els[i].appendChild(mainCube[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xmehqvx5/)

---

```
var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mainCubeClass')),
    i, j, el, mainCube = [],
    row;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    row = [];
    mainCube.push(row);
    for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) { //this is now 15
        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'letterPix';
        el.innerHTML = i + ':' + j
        row.push(el)
        els[i].appendChild(mainCube[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xmehqvx5/3/)

Comment: `className = '.letterPix'` bad class name.

Comment: What is the criteria for judging a class name as bad or good?

Comment: I began suspecting that was my issue after I posted this question, I even wrote it in the comments. Thanks @Arun P Johny you cleared up mix up between how I was basically overriding `mainCube` with empty arrays, also, I didn't know .appendChild was not okay in Arrays. Makes sense.

Comment: ooohh, nevermind, I see why it's a bad class name, because of the DOT. Damnit.